# Taking backup of data in a table

Tags: sql

Is there some way to backup the data in a table in sql server by using sql scripts. Note: I dont want to take the backup of the whole database.

And later on restore the same data back in case of any failure.
Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Are we talking about Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: +1 Saved me a good amount of time :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to have the backup. You can [create a new table as the result on a query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtableas.html), which looks like this: `CREATE TABLE foobar AS SELECT bar, baz FROM foo;`.

You can also look in the documentation of your DB if the bachup programms accept the dump of specified tables only. PostgreSQL can do this with the [--table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/app-pgdump.html) parameter, mysql [seems to do this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) when the table names are listed after the database name.

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008 [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) has a "Generate Insert Statements" function that can script out all the data in a table.

Answer (score 1):

1 Generate script of the table

2 Bcp out the data to text file